# Override label in Django Forms

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have 3 sections with identical fields, except for label on "title" field. 
For all of them I'm using same Django Form.

In views I have:

```
def get(self):
    context = self.CONTEXT_CLASS(self.MODEL_CLASS)
    context.messages = self.get_messages()
    context.section1 = InvoiceContentForm()
    context.section2 = InvoiceContentForm()
    context.section3 = InvoiceContentForm()
    self.render_jinja('templates/invoice/add_edit.html', context.as_dict)
```

My form:

```
class InvoiceContentForm(forms.Form):
"""Form for content of given section in add/edit invoice page."""
DEFAULT_ATTRS = {'class': 'form-control'}

title = forms.CharField(
    help_text='Title should be up to 24 characters long.',
    label=u'Title',
    required=True,
    widget=FormTextInput(),
)
(...)
```

Is there any way I can change title's label on `InvoiceContentForm()` while assigning it to `context.section1 = InvoiceContentForm()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override its constructor

```
class InvoiceContentForm(forms.Form):
     def __init__(self, title, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['title'].label = title

context.section1 = InvoiceContentForm('foo')
```

Comment: I think it should be `super(InvoiceContentForm, self)`, but apart from that works like a charm, thank you! Will mark ready in few minutes.

Comment: @pythonist, python 3 doesnt require the args, but yes you're correct if your using python 2.7 you will need that. No worries!